# Ambiguous references to assertEquals

Tags: java, assert

```
days = DayHelper.getInstance().getDays();
Assert.assertNotNull(days);
Assert.assertEquals(5, days.size());

final Day day = days.get(0);
Assert.assertNotNull(day);
Assert.assertEquals("01/10/2018", day.getId());
Assert.assertEquals("Mon", day.getDay());
Assert.assertEquals(1450, day.getQuota()); //Red underlined
Assert.assertEquals(41, day.getWeekno());  //Red underlined
Assert.assertEquals("Inserted duing DayHelperTest", day.getNote());
```

In the 'final day' block three of the Asserts compile without issue ... `String` expected and actual `String` comes from database

The two that are underlined in red expect `Integer` and get an `Integer`.

However, I cannot get rid of the Error below!!!

> Error:(56, 19) java: reference to assertEquals is ambiguous both method assertEquals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) in org.junit.Assert and method assertEquals(long,long) in org.junit.Assert match

Can somebody help please.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `1450L` and `41L` to make it explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I get errors like this with `assertEquals`, it's because I'm trying to assert that a `Long` object returned from a method is equal to `long` primitive value.

Either both arguments should be primitive `long`s

```
assertEquals(1450L, (long) day.getQuota());
```

(which risks a `NullPointerException` if `getQuota()` returns null, but your test would be failing anyway)

Or both arguments should be objects

```
assertEquals(Long.valueOf(1450), day.getQuota());
```

Comment: This did the job!!

Assert.assertEquals(1450L, (long) day.getQuota());
Assert.assertEquals(41L, (long) day.getWeekno());

Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Assert.assertEquals(1450L, day.getQuota());
Assert.assertEquals(41L, day.getWeekno());
```

Notice the `L` in front of the numbers? that's the way we specify that the comparison is made between `long` values.